# oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver on linux

Tags: java, oracle, jar, driver

I created a .jar file on my Eclipse installation (Windows10) and I need to export it to a Linux server to execute a Java program.

The .jar has ben built with ANT, where I specified the two .jar libraries:

- one for a specific class I need to use;
- the other is the **ojdbc6.jar**    jar I need to get the driver (which allowsm me connect to the Oracle database). Such connection works on local machine and targets to the Oracle 12.c database installed onto the Linux environment.

The two .jars are listed into the build.xml file, which is built with ANT.

When I import the file into Linux environment - in an installation of IBM Infosphere Datastage - such software recognizes the files and the compiled classes, as one of them has an exposed method that I correctly invoke.

This is the class which causes the error (it works on Windows 10, Windows 7 Eclipse environments).

```
public static void loadDriver(){
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("*** DriverManager error: driver not found ***");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error I find on Linux is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver that I have when I execute the command contained into the **try** clause. It works on Windows7 and Window10 (local machines).

Where am I wrong?

---

Further details. This is the build classpath:

```
<path id="myproject.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/ojdbc6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/ccjava-api.jar"/>
</path>
```

When I unzip the .jar file, I have (among the other files) the lib folder, which contains the two libraries ojdbc6.jar and ccjava-api.jar

Comment: why you're calling registerDriver?you're not supposed to call it in your code as its done automatically in latest jdbc apis..

Comment: The `ClassNotFoundException` means that you don't have ojdbc6.jar in the classpath when you run it on the Linux server. Make sure that jar file is in the proper place.

Comment: Hi @Jesper, well I have the ojdbc6.jar into the lib folder. Futhermore, I have this code into the build.xml file     <path id="capitalreporting.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/ojdbc6.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/ccjava-api.jar"/>
    </path> 
 What is wrong?

Comment: That you have it in your Ant build file, or in the classpath when you *compile* your code, is not important. It needs to be in the right place on the Linux server at *runtime* as well.

Comment: OK @Jesper and thanks. What should I do/install on Linux? Or should I need to modify the build.xml file?

Comment: you need to export built jar from windows to linux using ftp client like winscp or filezilla

Comment: @SagarKadu I am already using filezilla to import the .jar file, which is then uploaded into the target software (IBM Infosphere Datastage) which recognizes the file as I want. The problem I ecounter is the ClassNotFoundException. What should I install on Linux?

Comment: You say it's running on IBM Infosphere Datastage - I'm not familiar with that, so I don't know where you should deploy the Oracle driver jar in that environment. Take a look at the documentation of that product, or ask someone (maybe a colleague) who knows more about that.

Comment: @Jesper: Problem solved! I needed to put two configuration files within the Datastage installation folder, targeting to the Java class in use into my .jar. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I needed to put two configuration files within the Datastage installation folder, targeting to the Java class in use into my .jar.